# Calculate route and get route image using here.com rest api (nokia maps / navteq)

Tags: php, rest, here-api, navteq

How can I use here.com's REST api in order to get an image of a route calculation?
I know I can do this using the Javascript API, but, I cannot let the user see the waypoints exact coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly , you can achieve what you are looking for using the Map Image API, following link illustrates an example

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map-image/map-image-with-routes

Comment: i was able to solve this.. Turns out, you have to get the points first, and then plot the route on a map image yourself.